# How do you apply "flux-rule" in free space?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-circuits, maxwell-equations, electromagnetic-induction

Faraday's law of induction states that, the tangential component of the force per unit charge$^*$; EMF produced in a loop of wire, is equal to change in the magnetic flux through the loop,
$$\int_C \mathbf{E}. d \mathbf{S} = -\dfrac{\partial \mathbf{B}}{\partial t}$$

But when even I don't have a loop of wire, there is an electric field produced due to the change in the magnetic field. How to apply the same rule here, are we supposed to consider an imaginary loop and do the calculation?

***Sub-Questions:***

$^*$  Why is this equal to the work done on a single charge that travels once around the circuit ?

And is the following right?
When there's change in magnetic flux through a loop of wire, an electric field is produced, which curls around space, but only inside the the conductor(wire), the electrons are free to move, and hence we detect a current. But an electric field **exists** everywhere out of the loop of wire?

Comment: This rule applies for any curve $C$, whether or not that curve follows a loop of wire.

Comment: @knzhou so my second statement in the "sub-question" is true?